# How to push the values into array after adding some x amount to each value using javascript?

Tags: javascript

i want to take each value from an array and add some value to it and push it to new array.

i have done that in a very basic way. is there some way to do it in single statement or something thats nice and not repetitive like below,

```
  const first_array = [10, 20, 30];
  let final_array = [];
  const extra_value = 150;
  final_array[0] = first_array[0] + extra_value;
  final_array[1] = first_array[1] + extra_value;
  final_array[2] = first_array[2] + extra_value;
```

Could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: `first_array.map(e => e + 150);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the values to add extra values using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
final_array = first_array.map( x => x + extra_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.map()` to achieve this:

```
first_array.map(e => e + extra value);
```

Map will iterate over every value in your array and execute the function (in this case `e => e + extra value` for every value.